# Элемент после overflow

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему второй `<a>` идет не в одной горизонтальной линии с первым `<a>`

```css
.one {
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 50px; 
  display: inline-block;
}
.two {
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="one">Тест</a>
<a href="" class="two">Тест1</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что он своим низом встаёт по базовой линии текста.

```css
.one {
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 50px; 
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.two {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="one">Тест</a>
<a href="" class="two">Тест1</a>
```